# How to print parent taxonomy term name in a block?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Using Drupal 7, I want to create a simple block that will be on all taxonomy term pages that will show the first parent of the current term (there will be a tree of parents, but I want just the next highest).

The below code works to pull the current term name, but I'm unsure how to go about pulling the parent term  of this term page.

```
$current = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
if ($current):
echo $current->name;
endif;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a new question to get the answer (PHP is not my strong point).

$parent is actually an array, so it's output is a little different.  There's likely many ways of doing it, but

```
echo reset($parent)->name;
```

worked for me.

Comment: if $parent is an array, the correct way to access it is `$parent['name']`

Answer (score 1):

You get the parent term with [taxonomy_get_parents($tid)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/7). So you can just add:

```
$parent = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid);
if ($parent){
  echo $parent->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am getting an error with the first line.  Notice: Undefined variable, and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval()

Comment: Silly me, I removed the previous code so there was no $current variable.  I added it back, now I only have the error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() " on the code line "echo $parent->name;".

Comment: This is also being used in a simple text block with the PHP filter option, not sure if that is causing this not to work as maybe this code is to be used in a template only?

Comment: Adding print_r($parent); shows that it is pulling the data correctly, I just don't know PHP/Drupal well enough to know why echo $parent->name; is not displaying properly.